# Android : loading icon inside Button (as Left Drawable) shows but NO perform spin - animation

Tags: android, button, sdk, android-animation

I m trying to animate a drawable icon(like an indeterminate circle progressbar) inside a button as "left drawable" for this I make a custom-class from MaterialButton to show and hide the progress icon as I like

```java
class LoadingButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.materialButtonStyle
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val progress = CircularProgressDrawable(context).apply {
        setStyle(CircularProgressDrawable.DEFAULT)

        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.MaterialButton, defStyleAttr, 0
        )

        val tint = a.getColor(R.styleable.MaterialButton_iconTint, 0)

        setColorSchemeColors(tint)
    }

    fun showLoading() {
        this.icon = progress
        progress.start()
    }

    fun hideLoading() {
        progress.stop()
        this.icon = null
    }
}
```

de fragment to test is like this

```java
Fragment:

class DemoFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        demo_action.showLoading()
    }
}
```

and layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <XXX.XXXXX.XXXX.ui.custom.LoadingButton
        android:id="@+id/demo_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="call action"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

when call to showLoading() , loading icon appears but no spin-animated is taken place. Anybody knows why? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you spin animation is getting caught up in the ripple animation of the *MaterialButton*. See the following:

[image]

As you can see, the spin animation runs whenever the ripple animation is running. You could dig into the source code to find out where the animation for the ripple is started and stopped and, maybe, apply some code that will prevent the ripple from interfering with your spin animation; however, I think it would be better to overlay the button with a spin animation view that you can make visible/invisible/gone as needed. The effect will be the same, an overlay is less likely to break and should be more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I debug source code and probably it s an android bug. I m going to report bug. Thanks